# 24 hour time from date string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get just the time and that too in 24 hour format from following string :

**7/2/2015 2:30:00 PM**

This is what I have tried :

```
-(NSString*)returnDate:(NSString*)dateString
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aaa"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateString];

   dateString = [date descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];



    NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

    NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
    NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
    NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - gmtOffset;

    NSDate *destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:date];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatters = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatters setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
    [dateFormatters setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatters setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatters setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];
    [dateFormatters setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    dateString = [dateFormatters stringFromDate: destinationDate];

    return dateString;
}
```

**Output : 4:30**

This is returning correct time but in 12 hour format. I want the time in 24 hour format.

**Desired output : 16:30**

Comment: Delete the "a" from the format, that is requesting am/pm. Also delete the ShortStyle and RelativeDate formatter statements. See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Comment: @zaph : Wao !!! Simply changed what all you suggested. It worked perfectly.

Comment: See my answer, see if it works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is way to much code in the question, try this:

```
NSString *dateString = @"7/2/2015 4:30:00 PM";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aaa"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: date];

NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString);
```

Output:

> dateString: 16:30

Comment: You also need to use the special locale of `en_US_POSIX` to avoid issues due to the user's 24-hour time setting on the device.

Comment: @zaph : I found one thing. This works fine when the iPhone's setting has been set to 12 hour but when it is changed to 24 hour format, I get dateString as 00:00. Any idea ?

Comment: In that case the 3rd statement : NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateString]; returns nil.

Comment: @maddy : Sorry, I didn't read your point. Absolutely correct and useful. Thanks.